# Nested for loop : List - Not getting the desired output

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, neural-network, nested-loops

What I want to do is to estimate the score of each peptide i.e. row

My code is as following:

```
import csv, math

def train_data(fname):
        #load csv training files
        peptide= []
        allele= []
        score = []
        with open (fname) as train:
                reader = csv.DictReader(train, delimiter='\t')
                for row in reader:
                        peptide.append(row['peptide'])
                        allele.append(row['allele'])
                        score.append(row['score'])

        return [peptide, allele, score]

def ff():
        peptide, allele, score = train_data('sample.txt')
        p={'A':(0.074+0.077)/2, 'R':(0.052+0.053)/2, 'N':(0.045+0.044)/2, 'D':(0.054+0.051)/2, 'C':(0.025+0.022)/2, 'Q':(0.034+0.035)/2, 'E':(0.054+0.056)/2, 'G':(0.074+0.074)/2, 'H':(0.026+0.025)/2, 'I':(0.068+0.064)/2, 'L':(0.099+0.096)/2, 'K':(0.058+0.058)/2, 'M':(0.025+0.024)/2, 'F':(0.047+0.048)/2, 'P':(0.039+0.041)/2, 'S':(0.057+0.059)/2, 'T':(0.051+0.053)/2, 'W':(0.013+0.014)/2, 'Y':(0.032+0.033)/2, 'V':(0.073+0.072)/2}
        for i in range(len(peptide)):
#                peptide[i]=list(peptide[i])
                peptide.append(peptide[i])
                for j in range(len(peptide[i])):
                        print(peptide[2][j])
                        #est_score+=p[peptide[i][j]]
                print ('---')
        print(peptide[2][1])

if __name__=='__main__':

        ff()
```

When I run this code what I get as output is all the peptide values i.e. ***peptide[i][j]*** for the print stmt in the loop but what I want is to get only ***peptide[2][j]*** values.
Also outside the loop it works fine.  ***print(peptide[2][1])*** gives the o/p perfectly fine i.e. the value '*A*'

my csv file is like this:

```
peptide score   allele  
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.190842    DRB1_0101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006301    DRB1_0301
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.066851    DRB1_0401
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006344    DRB1_0405
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.035130    DRB1_0701
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006288    DRB1_0802
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.176268    DRB1_0901
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.042555    DRB1_1101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.114855    DRB1_1302
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006377    DRB1_1501
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006296    DRB3_0101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.006313    DRB4_0101
AAAGAEAGKATTEEQ 0.070413    DRB5_0101
```

> What I want to do is to estimate the score of each peptide i.e. row
>   not all the rows together using:
>   **est_score+=p[peptide[i][j]]**

Comment: pepetide[i] is a string.  For j in range(len(peptide[i])) is going to loop through the j values, but then you are printing each individual character from peptide[2], not anything to do with peptide[i].

Comment: Can you please tell me then what should I do if I want to calculate the score for each row separately? What it's doing is calculating the score for all the rows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "calculate the score for each row separately".  Your file seems to have a score already for each row.  What is the calculation?  Your for loop for i in range(len(peptide)) is looping over each row as it is. so in side that loop peptide[1] = AAAGA..., score[1] = 0.190842 and allele[1] = DRB1_0101.  I don't know what it is you are trying to do with these values

Comment: p={'A':(0.074+0.077)/2, 'R':(0.052+0.053)/2, 'N':(0.045+0.044)/2, 'D':(0.054+0.051)/2, 'C':(0.025+0.022)/2, 'Q':(0.034+0.035)/2, 'E':(0.054+0.056)/2, 'G':(0.074+0.074)/2, 'H':(0.026+0.025)/2, 'I':(0.068+0.064)/2, 'L':(0.099+0.096)/2, 'K':(0.058+0.058)/2, 'M':(0.025+0.024)/2, 'F':(0.047+0.048)/2, 'P':(0.039+0.041)/2, 'S':(0.057+0.059)/2, 'T':(0.051+0.053)/2, 'W':(0.013+0.014)/2, 'Y':(0.032+0.033)/2, 'V':(0.073+0.072)/2}

Comment: I want to use the dictionary i.e. the values above to predict/ calculate the score... estimated_score -> est_score. for each peptide i.e the row. But what the code is doing is to add the score for all the peptides i.e. rows

Comment: answer has been updated to include the dict you provided

Comment: like for peptide AARETN score will be "
0.0755*0.0755*0.0525*0.055*0.052*0.0445
    (A)         (A)          (R)       (E)      (T)      (N)

Comment: if it was the answer you were looking for, kindly accept it as such :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv, math

p={'A':(0.074+0.077)/2, 'R':(0.052+0.053)/2, 'N':(0.045+0.044)/2, 'D':(0.054+0.051)/2, 'C':(0.025+0.022)/2, 'Q':(0.034+0.035)/2, 'E':(0.054+0.056)/2, 'G':(0.074+0.074)/2, 'H':(0.026+0.025)/2, 'I':(0.068+0.064)/2, 'L':(0.099+0.096)/2, 'K':(0.058+0.058)/2, 'M':(0.025+0.024)/2, 'F':(0.047+0.048)/2, 'P':(0.039+0.041)/2, 'S':(0.057+0.059)/2, 'T':(0.051+0.053)/2, 'W':(0.013+0.014)/2, 'Y':(0.032+0.033)/2, 'V':(0.073+0.072)/2}

def train_data(fname):
        #load csv training files
        peptide= []
        allele= []
        score = []
        with open (fname) as train:
                reader = csv.DictReader(train, delimiter='\t')
                for row in reader:
                        peptide.append(row['peptide'])
                        allele.append(row['allele'])
                        score.append(row['score'])

        return [peptide, allele, score]

def ff():
        peptide, allele, score = train_data('peptide.txt')
        for i in range(len(peptide)):
                est_score = 0
                for char in peptide[i]:
                    est_score += p[char]
                print("est_score: " + str(est_score), "\t: read_score: " + str(score[i]) )
                print ('---')
        print(peptide[2][1])

if __name__=='__main__':

        ff()
```

The est_score is always the same because in the file you have provided, the peptide is identical in each row.  This prints:

```
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.190842
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.006301
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.066851
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.006344
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.035130
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.006288
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.176268
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.042555
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.114855
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.006377
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.006296
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.006313
---
est_score: 0.9625000000000001   : read_score: 0.070413
---
A
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it is only printing `peptide[2][j]`, but it is printing it for many times, it's that what you want?

```
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
A
A
G
A
E
A
G
K
A
T
T
E
E
Q
---
A
```

both python2 and python3 gives me the same result.

Comment: {'T': 0.052, 'K': 0.058, 'G': 0.074, 'Q': 0.0345, 'D': 0.0525, 'E': 0.055, 'M': 0.0245, 'C': 0.0235, 'W': 0.0135, 'I': 0.066, 'L': 0.0975, 'S': 0.057999999999999996, 'P': 0.04, 'F': 0.0475, 'A': 0.0755, 'V': 0.0725, 'N': 0.0445, 'R': 0.0525, 'Y': 0.0325, 'H': 0.025500000000000002}

I want to use the dictionary i.e. the values above to predict/ calculate the score... estimated_score -> est_score. for each peptide i.e the row. But what the code is doing is to add the score for all the peptides i.e. rows